# Angular - Make dates of calendar green upon opening the popup

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend

I'm trying to make my calendar have a green background upon opening for all the dates in my dates list (which is a list of strings).

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.roomService.getReservableDatesFromRoom(room.roomName).subscribe(data => {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        this.dates.push(`${data[i].reservableDate[0]}-${data[i].reservableDate[1]}-${data[i].reservableDate[2]}`);
      }
    });
  }
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<mat-card class="demo-inline-calendar-card">
    <h2 class="text-center">Reserveerbare datums</h2>
    <mat-calendar #calendar (selectedChange)="select($event,calendar)" [dateClass]="isSelected"></mat-calendar>
</mat-card>
```

for visualization:

[image]

the dates list already gets filled upon entering this screen, but all values are red.

I already have a function (which works with the [dateClass] property) so when I select some date that it turns green. Also only after selecting 1 date the other dates in my list turn green as well, but I want to have them green without selecting 1 date:

```
isSelected = (date: any) => {
    if (date.isBefore(Date.now() - 1, 'day')) {
      return 'disabled-dates'
    }
    return this.dates.filter((x) => date.isSame(x)).length > 0 ? 'selected' : 'not-selected';
  };
```

If anyone knows how to do this, it will be appreciated a lot!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

the javascript object Date **has not** method isBefore **nor** isSame. They are method of the library `momentjs` of object of type `moment`

I imagine that you need make some like

```
if (moment(date).isBefore(moment()))
   return 'disabled-dates'
   return this.dates.find((x) => moment(date).isSame(x,'day'))? 'selected' :
                    'not-selected';
```

(It's not neccessary filter, simply find the first that fullfilled the condition)

But really you needn't use momentjs

When we work with dates we need take careful if the dates have UCT or not, the format,...

Futhermore, the "dateClass" function (your function `isSelect`) is executed with each day displayed in the calendar, so should be the most quicky than possible. it's interesting write `console.log(date)` to see the value

```
   console.log(date) //'Fri Jan 20 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0100'
```

So our dates are at 00:00:00

Imagine your service return an array of strings

```
  ['2023-01-05','2023-01-12','2023-01-26']
```

We are using two variables

```
  dates:number[]
  today:number
```

Yes, number, we are going to transform the array of string in arrays of number in the way

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataService.getDates().subscribe((res: any[]) => {
      const now = new Date();
      now.setHours(0, 0, 0);
      this.today = now.getTime();
      this.dates = res.map((x) => {
        const date = new Date(x);
        date.setHours(0, 0, 0);
        return date.getTime();
      });
    });
  }
```

Now our function becomes like

```
  dateClass: MatCalendarCellClassFunction<Date> = (date: Date, view) => {
    const time = date.getTime();
    if (time < this.today) return 'disabled-dates';
    return this.dates.find((x: number) => x == time)
      ? 'selected'
      : 'not-selected';
  };
```

The [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ervtp9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-date-class-example.ts). See that if we not use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None`, we need declare the .css in styles.sccs,

**Update** using an API that return days selected in a month

If we using an API that get the dates selected but not all else only for one month at time, we can not use `dateClass` else we need make "javaScript way".

First define a panelClass to our dainput datePicker and add the "opened) event

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
<mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2">
<mat-hint>MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
<mat-datepicker-toggle matIconSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker [dateClass]="dateClassAsync" #picker2 panelClass="picker2" (opened)="open(picker2.startAt)"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

We are using the dateClassAsync only to get the new month

```
  dateClassAsync: MatCalendarCellClassFunction<Date> = (date: Date, view) => {
    if (date.getDate() == 1) {
      setTimeout(()=>{
        this.showMonth(date);
      })
    }
    return '';
  };
```

And the open function

```
  open(date: any) {
    date = date || new Date();
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.showMonth(date);
    })
  }
```

Finally we use create the function showMonth that use `getElementsByClassName("picker2")` to get the overlay and  `getElementsByClassName("mat-calendar-body-cell")` to get the buttons. finally use `classList.add` to add the class

```
  showMonth(date: any) {
    this.dataService
      .getDateMonth(date.getMonth() + 1)
      .subscribe((dates: string[]) => {
        const cal = document.getElementsByClassName('picker2')[0];
        const days = cal.getElementsByClassName('mat-calendar-body-cell');

        const yearmonth =
          date.getFullYear() +
          '-' +
          ('00' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
          '-';
        const today = new Date();
        const todayTxt =
          today.getFullYear() +
          '-' +
          ('00' + (today.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) +
          '-' +
          ('00' + today.getDate()).slice(-2);
        for (var i = 0; i < days.length; i++) {
          const dateTxt =
            yearmonth + ('00' + i).slice(-2);
            console.log(dateTxt)
          if (dateTxt < todayTxt) days[i].classList.add('disabled-dates');
          else
            days[i].classList.add(
              dates.find((x: string) => x == dateTxt)
                ? 'selected'
                : 'not-selected'
            );
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem, but I appreciate your help. The problem is that upon opening my calendar dialog (which is another component), all the fields are red until I click 1 field. only then the other fields (which are in the list) turn green as well. I want this to be green upon instantiating the component

Comment: @DJFreeman then I feel your problem is that you not have the "dates" when you open the calendar. I update the answer and the stackblitz to take account this cases.

Comment: I have the dates when opening the calendar, and they are of type: Moment

Comment: I changed a few things with the help of your code so thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:
Just call the calendar.updateTodaysDate() function after pushing the values to your dates list:

```
this.roomService.getReservableDatesFromRoom(room.roomName).subscribe(data => {
      for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        this.dates.push(moment(`${data[i].reservableDate[0]}-${data[i].reservableDate[1]}-${data[i].reservableDate[2]}`).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      }
      this.calendar.updateTodaysDate();
    });
```

Now my calendar has a green background for all the dates which are in the dates-list

Answer (score 0):

Easy Solution :

```
 **<mat-calendar #calendar (selectedChange)="select($event,calendar)" [dateClass]="!isSelected"></mat-calendar>**
```

Instead Of

```
**<mat-calendar #calendar (selectedChange)="select($event,calendar)" [dateClass]="isSelected"></mat-calendar>**
```

You just need to apply the dateClass by default and to make that you may want to have a false value of isSelected property.

Comment: dateClass is not of type: Boolean so adding the ! doesn't work. It gives me the following error: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'MatCalendarCellClassFunction<any>'.

Comment: I said the isSelected Property not dateClass ,

Comment: add  "!isSelected"

Comment: I did that, but by adding ! to the isSelected you are making it of type boolean which is not what I'm trying to do

Comment: the isSelected is of type boolean not really sure what r u talking abt ?? the css class will be applied if the isSelected returned true